# Theme system for laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, themes, laravel-6

I am working on a control panel for a niche game server. I want a basic theme system for my app and the goal is to keep the theme assets (js/css/images) together with the views. I don't want the views in resources dir and the assets in public dir separately.

With that in mind; here's what I came up with.

Theme (views and assets) organised like this - i.e. default `views` dir removed:

[image]

new **config/site.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'theme' => 'default',
];
```

modified **config/views.php**

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('themes/' . config('site.theme')),
    ],

    ...
```

new route **routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('theme/{file?}', 'ThemeController@serve')
    ->where('file', '[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\/]+');
```

new controller **app/Http/Controllers/ThemeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class ThemeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param $file
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse
     */
    public function serve($file)
    {
        $siteConfig = config('site');

        $filePath = resource_path("themes/{$siteConfig['theme']}/{$file}");

        if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            exit;
        }

        $fileLastModified = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(filemtime($filePath))->format('D, j M Y H:i:s');
        $fileEtag = md5_file($filePath);
        $requestFileEtag = request()->getETags()[0] ?? null;

        if (!empty($requestFileEtag) && strcmp($fileEtag, $requestFileEtag) === 0) {
            header("Last-Modified: {$fileLastModified}");
            header("Etag: {$fileEtag}");
            header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
            exit;
        }

        return response()->file($filePath, [
            'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=' . ($siteConfig['themeFilesCacheForMinutes'] * 60),
            'Etag' => $fileEtag,
            'Last-Modified' => $fileLastModified,
            'Content-Type' => $this->guessMimeType($filePath)
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param $filePath
     * @return false|string
     */
    private function guessMimeType($filePath) {
        $ext = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        switch ($ext) {
            case 'css':
                return 'text/css; charset=UTF-8';
            case 'js':
                return 'text/javascript; charset=UTF-8';
            default:
                return File::mimeType($filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

With that setup; if I want to include an asset from my theme, e.g. `css/sb-admin-2.min.css` in my master layout in `<head>...</head>`, this is what I do:

```
<link href="{{ url('theme/css/sb-admin-2.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

So, using this technique I can keep the views and assets together and php to serve the static asset with caching capability (via headers + etag).

I've tested this locally and it works, initial load takes approx 900ms and once the cache is warmed up, it loads the page under 500ms.

My question; is this a bad approach? i.e. serving static files using php? is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you are waisting all the cache system that uses the browsers and the servers... all the pages will have a load time very long, instead of just the first if you put all the css together

Comment: With Laravel Mix (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix) you can compile your assets to public dir, while working on resource dir. That way there is no need to use a controller to serve the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to package blades and static assets as an individual replaceable theme, just create a package for each theme and select desired theme using dependency injection. Inside each theme's ServiceProvider publish your assets to public directory.